# Are there separate Ministers of Magic for each country

Tags: harry-potter

This passage from *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* suggests that there are separate Ministers of Magic for each country;

> "How do you do, how do you do?". said Fudge, smiling and bowing to Mrs Malfoy. "And allow me to introduce you to Mr Oblansk-Obalonsk-Mr-well, he's the Bulgarian Minister of Magic, and he can't understand a word I am saying anyway, so never mind......" {the Quidditch World Cup}

So, are there actually separate Ministers of Magic for each country?

Comment: The quote itself answers your question. In the same way that Beauxbatons‎, Drumstrang, Mahoutokoro, and so on confirm that every (or most of them) have their own School of Magic; this quote confirms that all countries (or most of them) have their own Ministry of Magic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, yes.

1. We know they DO exist from that exact quote you provided from *GoF*.
2. We have another examoke of another countrie's MoM in [Joshua Sankara](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Joshua_Sankara) of Burkina Faso (*Pottermore - New from J.K. Rowling: "Quidditch World Cup (1990-2014)"*)
3. British Ministry of Magic has office for liasing with other countries' Ministries (Department of International Magical cooperation).

   That wouldn't have been necessary if THE single Minister of Magic would be in charge of all countries.
4. From *HBP*, we find out that Fudge (and later, Scrimgeour) are local because Fudge had "the same kind of week" that British PM was having. If he was in charge of the global world, he wouldn't have been ONLY concerned with Great Britain.
5. In general, ALL of known MoMs, in ALL known details of their lives, seem to have been extremely British-local:

   http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Minister_for_Magic (many of the details there are sourced from Pottermore MoM page)

Comment: Is the USA Minister of Magic called the Secretary of Magic or the Magician General?

Comment: @user14111 - non canon info. Probably Tzar since 2008 :)

Answer (score 4):

## There seem to be, for the majority of countries at least, if not all.

It seems like there’s a Ministry of Magic in almost every country, though this is certainly not confirmed for sure. There may be some countries without many wizards that don’t have one, and there also may be some countries where the governing body of wizards isn’t called a Ministry of Magic but instead has a different name. However, at least from what we see, it seems like the majority of countries do have a Ministry of Magic.

The size of the country may have an effect on whether it has a Ministry of Magic, though it’s not really clear. There’s only one very small country that is said to possibly have one. Andorra, a very small country, likely has its own Ministry of Magic. (“Likely”, not “certainly”, because Barty Crouch Sr. was losing his mind when he happened to refer to their Ministry, so his words shouldn’t necessarily be considered true, though they still might be.)

> “Yes, my son has recently gained twelve O.W.Ls, most satisfactory, yes, thank you, yes, very proud indeed. Now, if you could bring me that memo from the Andorran Minister for Magic, I think I will have time to draft a response …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 28 (The Madness of Mr Crouch)*</sup></sub>

There are Ministries of Magic in several countries in Asia; India, Pakistan, Bangladesh, Iran, and Mongolia - all fairly large countries, so doesn’t prove that all countries have one.

> “Quidditch has never achieved great popularity in the East, as the flying broomstick is a rarity in countries where the carpet is still the preferred mode of travel. The Ministries of Magic in countries such as India, Pakistan, Bangladesh, Iran and Mongolia, all of whom maintain a flourishing trade in flying carpets, regard Quidditch with some suspicion, though the sport does have some fans among witches and wizards on the street.” 
> <sub><sup>*Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

There’s one in New Zealand. It’s (never mentioned whether Australia has one, though they do have Quidditch teams, so there’s likely some form of wizarding government, even if it’s not called a Ministry of Magic.

> “The New Zealand Ministry of Magic has certainly spent much time and money preventing Muggles getting hold of Maori art of that period which clearly depicts white wizards playing Quidditch (these carvings and paintings arc now on display at the Ministry of Magic in Wellington).” 
> <sub><sup>*Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

There’s one in Germany as well. (In articles on Pottermore written by JKR, there are said to be Ministries of Magic in France, Liechtenstein, and the question already refers to the one in Bulgaria.)

> “Strict controls by the German Ministry of Magic, however, have reduced Erkling killings dramatically over the last few centuries and the last known Erkling attack, upon the six-year-old wizard Bruno Schmidt, resulted in the death of the Erkling when Master Schmidt hit it very hard over the head with his father’s collapsible cauldron.” 
> *<sub><sup>- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them (textbook)</sup></sub>*

There’s also one in Norway.

> “Kneen’s letter is deposited in the archives of the Norwegian Ministry of Magic.”

The countries we know for certain to have Ministries of Magic are all fairly populous. It’s unclear whether the much smaller and less populated countries, like Tuvalu, with a population of less than 10,000, would also have a Ministry of Magic or if there needs to be above a certain number of wizards before a country gets its own Ministry of Magic.

## The *Fantastic Beasts* movie shows the USA has MACUSA instead.

In the *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* movie, we see the American wizard government, which is called the Magical Congress of the United States of America, usually abbreviated to MACUSA. While the organization itself was featured in the movie, its background was published on Pottermore.

> MACUSA was modeled on the Wizards’ Council of Great Britain, which predated the Ministry of Magic. Representatives from magical communities all over North America were elected to MACUSA to create laws that both policed and protected American wizardkind. 
> <sub><sup>*[The Magical Congress of the United States of America (MACUSA) (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/macusa)*</sup></sub>

Instead of a Minister of Magic, MACUSA is led by a president.

> “High up, a gigantic dial with many cogs and faces emblazoned with the legend: MAGICAL EXPOSURE THREAT LEVEL. The hand on the dial points to SEVERE: UNEXPLAINED ACTIVITY. Behind hangs an imposing portrait of a majestic-looking witch: SERAPHINA PICQUERY, MACUSA’s President.” 
> <sub><sup>*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup></sub>

However, it has the same purpose as a Ministry of Magic would: enforce the laws of the wizarding world and ensure that wizards are not discovered by the Muggles.

Comment: How does it happen that magical countries correspond so neatly to muggle countries? Does that mean that whenever muggle boundaries are changed, whenever muggle countries are divided or united or conquered, the magical boundaries have to change the same way? Were the British wizards watching the muggle world's Scottish Independence Referendum with great interest, to see if Scotland was going to have its own Ministry of Magic? In the U.S. did the wizards of the Southern States have their own Magical Congress from 1861 to 1865?

Comment: @user14111 well, for the second question, I guess yes. Nobody will be able go to Hogwarts (let alone hop on board the Hogwarts Express) anymore if the King's Cross Station becomes completely destroyed (like in a muggle war, for example). If there are other examples that show how the magical world might be related somehow to the muggle world, then this will answer your first question. But obviously, the magical world has to co-exist with the muggle world -- Earth!

Answer (score 2):

[The writeup "Mahoutokoro" on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/mahoutokoro) gives further evidence that there are multiple Ministers of Magic, since it mentions "trial at the Japanese Ministry for Magic".